# Argument 1 must be of the type string or null, object given

Tags: laravel, arguments, typeerror

I get this error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CNld.jpg
I haven't changed much either since it worked, mainly the html, weird.
https://github.com/cubesacube/project

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I think your `redirect()` on CustomerController is the problem. For some reason `redirect()` doesnt allowed us to use it without params.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in your `CustomerController` at line [20](https://github.com/cubesacube/project/blob/54e70eb5c2908c9a60cf752d48726a8ecffae95b/app/Http/Controllers/CustomerController.php#L20):

```php
public function store() {
    Customer::create($this -> validatedData());
    return redirect(); //this is the problem
}
```

`redirect()` needs route name or url path like `redirect('/home')` or `redirect('login')`

**Reference**
[HTTP Redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects)

Answer (score 0):

But due to being using php8.1. I got the same error.

Solution:
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Nginx

Installed the php7.4-fpm version and its extensions.

```
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php && apt-get update

    apt-get install php7.4-{cgi,cli,fpm,pdo,gd,mbstring,mysqlnd,opcache,xml,zip}

  sudo apt-get install  php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-fpm php7.4-mysql php7.4-zip php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-curl php7.4-xml php7.4-bcmath openssl php7.4-json php7.4-tokenizer`
```